# $_SESSION not updating views on other pages

Tags: php, session

php

```
$post_id = $_GET['post_id'];

if(!isset($_SESSION['view_counter'])){
            $_SESSION['view_counter'] = $post_id;
            $increment_views->execute();
        }
```

mysql query

```
    $increment_views = $connectDB->prepare("UPDATE database.table 
SET post_views = post_views + 1 WHERE post_id = $post_id;");
```

As I was trying to add page view counter using sessions, just stuck on this problem. This seems simple but not able to get my head around. Lets say I'm currently on `www.website.com/posts.php?post_id=3`. So at first no session is set then the code runs, the session is set, and view is incremented, looks fine! Then I browse to `www.website.com/posts.php?post_id=5`, but then the view is not incremented because the session is already there. So how will I be differentiate sessions in that case. So it won't think that these two pages are the same.

Comment: Well, why do you check if the session was set in the first place? I'm not able to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: trying to add view counter on each post. I just want to prevent view getting counted on every refresh.

Comment: What is view counter? What does `increment_view->execute()` do?

Comment: @msfoster, updated my code above.

Comment: The query use `$post_id`, where is this assigned? How is the session related to the query?

Comment: `$post_id` is taken from the header. Not sure what kind of relation between session and query you are referring to.

Comment: Why are you using sessions at all? This would work perfectly if you just execute() right after you assign `$post_id`

Comment: yes it would work, but every page refresh by the user would increment the view? am I right? to prevent that I guess.

Comment: Then I suggest you filter on IP address. Otherwise you need to create a new session for each `post_id`.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned, you should probably filter on IP, but here is a suggestion:

```
$post_id = $_GET['post_id'];

if(!isset($_SESSION["viewcount_".$post_id])) {
  $_SESSION["viewcount_".$post_id] = true;
  $increment_views->execute();
}
```

Comment: This is the exact same thing, I was about to write.

Answer (score 1):

I would store a session variable, something like `$_SESSION['countedPostId']=$post_id` then, on refresh, check to make sure the `$_GET['postid']` is the same as `$_SESSION['countedPostId']`.  If yes, it's already been counted.  If no, you need to recount.

If I've interpreted your question correctly, that is.

WORKAROUND EDIT:

Perhaps try storing an array of "already-incremented" post_id's in the sessions variable in order to prevent issues from going back/forward.

Comment: yes this is helpful and I've tried as well. But then when I go back and forth, the views would also be updated. Lets say I would go from `$post_id = 3` to `$post_id = 5` or vice versa, so that would increment the views as well. But that surely prevents the every page refresh.

Comment: Answer edited to suggest a workaround to this problem.